# Convert DateTime to String PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have already researched a lot of site on how can I convert PHP DateTime object to String.  I always see "String to DateTime" and not "DateTime to String"

PHP DateTime can be echoed, but what i want to process my DateTime with PHP string functions.

My question is how can I make PHP dateTime Object to a string starting from this kind of code:

```
$dts = new DateTime(); //this returns the current date time
echo strlen($dts);
```

Comment: Why do you want to process your DateTime with string functions? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: some kind of a datetime validator? in php

Answer (score 531, accepted):

You can use the [`format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method of the `DateTime` class:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If `format` fails for some reason, it will return `FALSE`. In some applications, it might make sense to handle the failing case:

```
if ($result) {
  echo $result;
} else { // format failed
  echo "Unknown Time";
}
```

Comment: +1 It works. Can you please also tell how to check for null (in same line) before doing this conversion. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Watt, good point! I've expanded the example to show how the failing case might be handled.

Comment: you forgot the timezone,
instead use `$date->format('c')` or `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s Z')` or `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T')`

Comment: what using statement do you need to be able to use ->format? It says missing something in Zend

Comment: You can use this shorter form `$result = (new DateTime('2000-01-01'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` since PHP 5.4. Watch here: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php _Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar()._

Answer (score 25):

```
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 23):

The simplest way I found is:

```
$date   = new DateTime(); //this returns the current date time
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
echo $result . "<br>";
$krr    = explode('-', $result);
$result = implode("", $krr);
echo $result;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 18):

There are some predefined formats in `date_d.php` to use with `format` like:

```
define ('DATE_ATOM', "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP");
define ('DATE_COOKIE', "l, d-M-y H:i:s T");
define ('DATE_ISO8601', "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO");
define ('DATE_RFC822', "D, d M y H:i:s O");
define ('DATE_RFC850', "l, d-M-y H:i:s T");
define ('DATE_RFC1036', "D, d M y H:i:s O");
define ('DATE_RFC1123', "D, d M Y H:i:s O");
define ('DATE_RFC2822', "D, d M Y H:i:s O");
define ('DATE_RFC3339', "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP");
define ('DATE_RSS', "D, d M Y H:i:s O");
define ('DATE_W3C', "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP");
```

Use like this:

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$string = $date->format(DATE_RFC2822);
```

Comment: You can use constant of DateTime (eg DateTime::ISO8601), it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter way using list. And you can do what you want with each date component.

```
list($day,$month,$year,$hour,$min,$sec) = explode("/",date('d/m/Y/h/i/s'));
echo $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year.' '.$hour.':'.$min.':'.$sec;
```

Answer (score 2):

Its worked for me

```
$start_time   = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_time);
$current_date = new DateTime();
$diff         = $start_time->diff($current_date);
$aa           = (string)$diff->format('%R%a');
echo gettype($aa);
```