# datetime only returning date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table with column date set to datetime.  When i return and get the date from row it is only returning the date and not the time.

```
 $date = $row["date"];
```

I have tried to format as below and I get the error of:

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given

```
 $date = date_format($row["date"], 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

How do I get the whole value?

Comment: what does $row["date"] show..?

Comment: did you check if $row["date"] shows a date?

Comment: SELECT follower_id, myMember, date FROM follow WHERE myMember='$id' ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: datetime in sql show date and time as expected.  $row[date] returns only date.

Comment: It sounds like this is not a php formatting issue, but a sql "extract date and time from column" issue. What makes you say "datetime in sql show date and time as expected"? In what way are you looking at the DB when it is "right"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your select statement, cast the date into datetime. ex

```
SELECT CAST(date AS DATETIME) newDate
```

and retrieve it as

```
$dateTime = strtotime($row["newDate"]);
```

Comment: I did this and the format is not as I Need.  When i tyr to format using

$date = date_format($dateTime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given

Comment: When you use `select cast` as in this answer, what does $row["date"] contain? If it contains date and time (but in the wrong format), you should then be able to use `date_format($row["newDate"], 'Y-m-d H:i:s');` - what do you get?

Comment: Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given

I have to redefine my issue.  $date = $row["date"];echo $date; and I get a good date on my original query.  The problem is when I pass it with ajax the date is truncated.  I pass it this way:<div style="clear:both"; class="div_container" date_time=\"'.$date.'\" post_author_id=\"'.$id.'\">.     Then I pass it like this. url: "get_followers_list_scroll.php?date_time="+ $(".div_container:last").attr('date_time')+"&post_author_id="+$(".div_container:last").attr('post_author_id'),

Comment: The problem was the space when I was tying to pass this with ajax.  I corrected this by just changing the format and then stripping this on the receiving page.

Comment: $date = date_format(date_create($row["date"]), 'Y-m-d-H:i:s');

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your string $date to the right type. I had to try a few things to get this right, but this now behaves on my machine:

```
$thisDate = "2013-02-02 22:17:06"; // example you gave, as a string

$timezone="America/New_York";      // machine was complaining when I didn't specify

$DT = new DateTime($thisDate, new DateTimeZone($timezone)); // this really is a DateTime object

echo $DT->format('Y-m-d H:i');    // you can echo this to the output

$dateString = $DT->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  // or format it into a string variable
```

Comment: Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, integer given

Comment: Very nice.  The echo is giving the correct datetime however the $date value is still just the date.

Comment: I have to take that back.  Now that I echo date I see it is correct but when I pass the value to another php page the time is getting truncated.

Comment: What happens if you use a line like this: `$dateAsString = $DT->format('Y-m-d H:i')` ? Note I left of the `:s` deliberately to make sure "I was actually doing something to the original value". I am pretty sure that [makes an actual string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569053/convert-datetime-to-string)...

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$date = date_format(new DateTime($row['date']), "Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

OR

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Comment: Still only passes the date.  The date in my columns are like this "2013-02-02 22:17:06" so they are datetime. 

2013-02-02 is what the row is extracting.

Comment: second option returns 2013-02-02.  I agree the data in the column is formated as date time but php query only returns date.  The reason I need this is I am using infinite scrolling and passing the date but my date being passed is only using the date and not the time so I am missing the entire day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to date type first. Then date_format() will work. Try the following.

```
$date = date_format(date_create($row["date"]), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Good Luck