# How to convert 26-Feb-2013 type date fomat into 26-02-2013 format using php

Tags: php

I want to convert 26-Feb-2013  type date fomat into 26-02-2013 format using php
I can do this in long way as following

```
$date='26-Feb-2013';
$datew=explode('-',$date);
$mounth=$datew[1];
if($mounth=='Jan'){
$mounth=='Jan'

}
elseif($mounth=='feb'){
$mounth=='Feb'

}
```

and again using implode function to convert 26-02-2013 format
but i want to know any easy way to do this 
is there any way to do this?

Comment: See a conversation that is directly relevant at [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669863/datetime-only-returning-date/14669875#comment20505900_14669875)

Comment: but problam is i haven't  idea  about convert Feb into 2

Comment: @master3w You don't have to. PHP has this sort of thing built in.

Comment: My earlier link and suggested function would have allowed you to find the answer... You learn more that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date='26-Feb-2013';
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)); // prints 26-02-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $date='26-Feb-2013';
   $datew= date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date));
```

Fixed sorry should have tested before submitting

Comment: Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in F:\project\wamp\www\oo\date.php on line 3 error com

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
 $date='26-Feb-2013';
 echo $datew = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date));
```