# PHP - How to get datetime string from DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

I've made a DateTime object using

```
$currtime = DateTime::createFromFormat("YmdHi");
```

Is there a way to get a string or an integer, which contains, for example, `201604041825`?

```
$currtime->modify("+2 hours");
$newtime = $currtime->format("YmdHi");
```

returned

```
$newtime = 2147483647
```

Comment: Investigate [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569053/convert-datetime-to-string-php

Comment: I've now used the current time. After that, I did `$datetime->modify("+2 hours");` and then `$datetime->format("YmdHi")` returned 2147483647

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock Yes, I've deleted comment. I misunderstood your question. See duplicate link for answer. You can use `->format('YmdHi')`

Comment: Your example is wrong: `DateTime::createFromFormat` fails without second parameter. Show you second parameter, the problem is in it.

Comment: I've now used `$currtime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i"));`

Comment: I suspect you have some typo in real `->format()`. See [this demo](https://3v4l.org/duSYH)... it works

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Code: `$currtime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i"));
$currtime->modify("+2 hours");
$querys[] = "UPDATE wronglogins SET logincount = ".($bans->logincount + 1)." WHERE IP = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."';";
$querys[] = "UPDATE wronglogins SET lcend = ".$currtime->format("YmdHi")." WHERE IP = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."';";`

Comment: have you the wrong result after printing the `$query` in php or in your MySQL record?

Comment: I'm getting 20160404..... in the query, but a wrong result in my mysql record

Comment: What kind of field is your `lcend` field? (date, datetime, varchar, int...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you

```
$current_date_object= new DateTime();
$current_date_object->modify("+2 hours");
$current_date_string= $current_date_object->format("Y-m-d H:i:sO");
```