# Cakephp not saving the selected value of date field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.8

I have this problem, I am using cake 2.8.x, my cakephp application is not saving the selected value of the date field. It kept saving "1970-01-01" even if you selected "2016-02-02" . What could be wrong?

This is my code in the controller

```
$this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']));
$this->request->data['Jobapp']['dateofissue']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['dateofissue']));
$this->request->data['Jobapp']['expirydate']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['expirydate']));
```

and this is one of the field in the view file

```
<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('dayofbirth',array('label'=>'Date of Birth','type'=>'date','minYear'=>date('Y') - 90))?>
```

What could be the issue?

```
    'dayofbirth' => array(
        'day' => '12',
        'month' => '08',
        'year' => '1993'
    ),
    'maritalstatus' => 'emtpy',
    'nationality' => 'empty',
    'complexion' => '',
    'passportnumber' => '',
    'dateofissue' => array(
        'month' => '05',
        'day' => '25',
        'year' => '2016'
    ),
    'placeofissue' => '',
    'expirydate' => array(
        'month' => '05',
        'day' => '25',
        'year' => '2016'
    ),
```

Comment: Debug before saving in your add action?

Comment: @skywalker, I have debugged it, but i still get wrong values as the value in the debug , see below ''dayofbirth' => '1970-01-01 01:00:00',
  'maritalstatus' => 'emtpy',
  'nationality' => 'empty',
  'complexion' => '',
  'passportnumber' => '',
  'dateofissue' => '1970-01-01 01:00:00',
  'placeofissue' => '',
  'expirydate' => '1970-01-01 01:00:00','

Comment: Please show your controller action code in your question.

Comment: @skywalker check the post, i posted it up there

Comment: Where do you debug request data, before or after date conversion?

Comment: after date conversion, ok, let me debug before date conversion and see what it looks like , thaks

Comment: Yes, you are probably doing something wrong with date conversion there.

Comment: @skywalker, yeah, you are right, before the date coversion, the right selected value is displayed, I think the issue is from date conversion, please how do you think i can do the conversion ? '$this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']));
        $this->request->data['Jobapp']['dateofissue']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['dateofissue']));
        $this->request->data['Jobapp']['expirydate']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['expirydate']));'

Comment: Please post you data before conversion in your question, not comment.

Comment: Well there you go, construct your date with that array and use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569053/convert-datetime-to-string-php

Comment: see the error i got DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

Comment: see my code is anything wrong with it ?  $date = new dateTime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']);
            $result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']=$result;

Comment: Why are you trying to build a new datetime value manually in the first place? The CakePHP ORM does that automatically, given that your database columns are defined as proper `DATE/TIME` types.

Answer (score 0):

Your date fields are arrays. Try:

```
 $this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(implode('-',$this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth'])));
```

the same with other fields

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify date field, CakePHP takes care of it. So You can get rid of these lines:

```
 $this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['dayofbirth']));
 $this->request->data['Jobapp']['dateofissue']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['dateofissue']));
 $this->request->data['Jobapp']['expirydate']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->data['Jobapp']['expirydate']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of jquery ui, with which you can avoid date field modification withing controller.

In your view do the following changes,

```
<!-- Load the jquery & jquery ui library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:"yyyy-mm-dd"});
    });
</script>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('dayofbirth',['class'=>'datepicker']); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('dateofissue',['class'=>'datepicker']); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('expirydate',['class'=>'datepicker']); ?>
```

Please remove your controller code that processes input data. You should be then able to insert date in correct format.