# Php convert a date to string character

Tags: php

I have searched but I could not find out how to convert a date from a character string. For example string date is 18-08-2016 I want to convert 18 August 2016 How can I do?

Comment: Have you checked out this post yet? <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569053/convert-datetime-to-string-php>

Comment: I didn't see sorry thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input = '18-08-2016';
echo strftime('%d %B %Y',strtotime($input));// 18 August 2016
```

[Use this resource](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to format the output to your liking.