# How to store times into variable using php?

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to store time into variable which type is string, following is script

```
$time = '00:00:00';
foreach($GameLog->gamelogs->toArray() as $Data){
    $base = strtotime('00:00:00');
    $seconds = (strtotime($time) - $base) + (strtotime($Data['pivot']['time_spent']) - $base);
}

$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$minutes = floor($seconds / 60) % 60;
$seconds = $seconds % 60;
$ResultArray['time']   =  sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

where is `$Data['pivot']['time_spent']` has different times like

`00:05:30`
`00:03:25`
`00:12:39`

By above loop method I am unable to store the time, because it is returning wrong result. how can i fix the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to String PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569053/convert-datetime-to-string-php)

Comment: @Dave it's now duplicated you need to read the question properly

Comment: what's actually wrong with it? Tested and it returns a microtime as expected?

Comment: and try moving your code inside the foreach loop - all that will do is use the last iteration in the code outside the loop ..

Answer (score -1):

Try writing your times with '.' instead of ':' like :

```
$time = '00.00.00';
```

[See why here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php)

Comment: this is a mix of code-only and link-only - you should add relevant info from the link to keep it on SO for future users (that link may be dead in < 3 months for example)