# convert timestamp with t and z to local time in php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have a `datetime` value in this format `2019-07-01T05:21:08.148986Z` which is in `UTC`.

How can I convert this timestamp into `local` time in human readable format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to String PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569053/convert-datetime-to-string-php)

Comment: If you want to display it in the local timezone, then you will need some javascript to set it.

Comment: Why is the format you posted not *in human readable format*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FROM A DATETIME OBJECT:**

You just need to modify the timezone :

```
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get() ) );
echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s') . "\n";
```

You can also set a Time Zone beforehand :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

**FROM A STRING:**

Convert your date in timestamp :

```
$timestamp = strtotime($yourDate);
```

Then create a date using the timezone you want :

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s') . "\n";
```

You can also set a Time Zone beforehand :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```